# Once Drop Down is Selected, Disable specific text fields using Javascript and AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to disable certain text fields once a specific drop down item as been selected utilizing Javascript and AJAX.
My HTML code is as follows:

```
<html>
    <li>
        <span class="label">Rate Type: </span>
        <label class="alignleft">
        <select class="customSelect"name="Rate" onChange="findSelected()" id="Rate2">                           
            <option>Fixed</option>
            <option>Fixed</option>
            <option value="variable">Variable</option>
        </select>
    </label>    
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="label">Mortgage Interest Rate :</span>
        <label class="alignleft"><span class="percent">%</span><input type="text" class="textfield" value=5 name="Iint"/></label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="label multiline">Amount Borrower want to repay: </span>
        <label class="alignleft"><input type="text" class="textfield" value=10000 name="Ipay"/></label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="label multiline">Posted Interest Rate for Similar Mortgages</span>
        <label class="alignleft"><span class="percent">%</span><input type="text" class="textfield" value=3 name="Iintsim"/></label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="label">Mortgage Interest Rate :</span>
        <label class="alignleft twofield"><strong class="percent">%</strong><input type="text" class="textfield" value=1.30 Name="Mint" /></label>
    </li>

</html>
```

My Javascript code is as follows:

```
function findSelected(){ 
    var xhttpr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // xhttpr.open("GET","index.html",true);

    // xmlhttp.send();
    var rate= document.getElementById('Rate2'); 
    var variable = document.getElementById('variable'); 
    if(rate.value == "variable"){
        alert("hi");
        Iint.disabled=false;
        Ipay.disabled=false;
        Iintsim.disabled=false;

    } else {
        Iint.disabled=true;
        Ipay.disabled=true;
        Iintsim.disabled=true;
    }
}
```

I'm sure I am doing something, if not many, things wrong.
Please let me know.
Thanks!

Comment: Well, to start, you're missing the wrapping `<ul>`, and the `<body>` and then probably you'd want a `<head>` too. I mean that HTML is just not valid as it is right now.

Comment: why is there a jquery tag but only raw javascript? this would be alot less code with jquery. the html is bizzare.. indenting is horrible.. but you seem like a nice guy.. :)

Comment: Why do you have jquery in your question tags? Are you using jquery with this? It will make it a lot simpler actually!

Comment: I apologize, I must have subconsciously added that JQuery tag.
Additionally, I cut a lot of HTML out, my apologies for the confusion.  Also, I apologize for the horrendous indenting, StackOverflow was reading it as real HTML.  My apologies.

Comment: Haha, apologies for the concatenated post.  It looked a lot better when I was editing it :P

Comment: Have you tried `<select onchange="" >`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with something like this:

```
var $inputs = $('input'); // collection of inputs to disable
$('select').change(function(){
  $inputs.prop('disabled', $(this).val() === 'Variable');
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/udimos/1/edit

Comment: What should I substitute input with?
The name of the input? The class?

Comment: that thing you did with .prop() here is a pretty pretty line of code. +1

Comment: Additionally, there are multiple inputs.  Therefore, would I have to treat $inputs as an array or something?

Comment: @James Graham, I would just add a class to all the inputs that are going to be disabled and target those like `var $inputs = $('input.myclass')`

Comment: I now have:
 var $inputs = $('input.textfield');
$('select').change(function(){
  $inputs.prop('disabled', $(this).val() == 'Variable');});

It still isn't working unfortunately.  I'm sure it's starting my right in the face.  I apologize.

Comment: Mmmm...don't know, just check demo here http://jsbin.com/udimos/1/edit and try selecting "Three", it works fine, problem must be somewhere else...

Comment: Thank you for all your help man, much appreciated.
I'll keep chipping away at it.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that Iint, Ipay and IIntsim don't reference the DOM elements you want to change.  Try changing the code to:

```
function findSelected(){ 
var rate= document.getElementById('Rate2'); 
var variable = document.getElementById('variable'); 
if(rate.value == "variable"){
      alert("hi");
     document.getElementById('Iint').disabled=false;
     document.getElementById('Ipay').disabled=false;
     document.getElementById('Iintsim')disabled=false;

} else {

     document.getElementById('Iint').disabled=true;
     document.getElementById('Ipay').disabled=true;
     document.getElementById('Iintsim').disabled=true;
}
```

}

Comment: I replaced the Javascript code word-for-word verbatim.  Unfortunately it is still dysfunctional.  
I'm sure you just solved one of the many errors :P.
This is my first day with HTML/Javascript. Thanks for bearing with me!

Comment: As others have mentioned, your HTML needs some work as it isn't compliant with HTML standards and some browsers won't render it correctly.  
If you are using Internet Explorer, you may see a warning message about it blocking the webpage from running scripts or Active X controls - you need to choose "Yes" to let the code run.    
See answer below with the full code (you just need to put the javascript function between <script></script> tags within the <html></html> tags).

Answer (score 1):

You can't put an onclick event on an option of a select - you need to hook into the onchange event of the select instead.

You will also need to give each option a value, e.g.

```
<option value="variable">Variable</option>
```

Basically, you fire "onchange" and then check which item is selected in the dropdown and decide what to do within your function (note that you just pass this, not this.form1.Rate):

```
<select class="customSelect" name="Rate" onchange="javascript:OnChange(this);">


function OnChange(dropdown)
{
var myindex  = dropdown.selectedIndex
var SelValue = dropdown.options[myindex].value
//now you know which value is selected, you can test it and call your disableField
if(SelValue=='variable'){disableField();}  
}
```

have a look at this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/656/Using-JavaScript-to-handle-drop-down-list-selectio

Answer (score 0):

The full code should look like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <span class="label">Rate Type: </span>
        <label class="alignleft">
          <select class="customSelect"name="Rate" onChange="findSelected()" id="Rate2">                           
            <option>Fixed</option>
            <option>Fixed</option>
            <option value="variable">Variable</option>
          </select>
        </label>    
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="label">Mortgage Interest Rate :</span>
        <label class="alignleft"><span class="percent">%</span><input type="text" class="textfield" value=5 id="Iint"/></label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="label multiline">Amount Borrower want to repay: </span>
        <label class="alignleft"><input type="text" class="textfield" value=10000 id="Ipay"/></label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="label multiline">Posted Interest Rate for Similar Mortgages</span>
        <label class="alignleft"><span class="percent">%</span><input type="text" class="textfield" value=3 id="Iintsim"/></label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="label">Mortgage Interest Rate :</span>
        <label class="alignleft twofield"><strong class="percent">%</strong><input type="text" class="textfield" value=1.30 Name="Mint" /></label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the function should look like this:

```
function findSelected(){ 
  var rate= document.getElementById('Rate2'); 
  var variable = document.getElementById('variable'); 
  if(rate.value == "variable"){
    alert("hi");
    document.getElementById('Iint').disabled=false;
    document.getElementById('Ipay').disabled=false;
    document.getElementById('Iintsim').disabled=false;    
  } else {
    document.getElementById('Iint').disabled=true;
    document.getElementById('Ipay').disabled=true;
    document.getElementById('Iintsim').disabled=true;
  }
}
```

As others have suggested though, using JQuery would make the code simpler and easier to maintain and give you options such as live binding, which could be useful as your application develops.